# Python: Creating the "negative" of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this 64x64 2D array
[image]
the data for this array can be downloaded here - http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3s/1494223164755.txt

Now, I wish to make a copy of this array in which the areas that have the highest value receive the value of the areas with the lowest value and vice-versa. Is there a smart way of doing it in Python?

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: `a.max() - a` or `a.max() - a + a.min()` if you don't care or do for the range of values in output?

Comment: @Divakar, just a minor note: `a.max()+a.min()-a` is better than `a.max()-a+a.min()` because it avoids creating unnecessary temp arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data is stored in a 2dim numpy array `arr`, you can do:

```
arr2 = arr.max() + arr.min() - arr
```